# How do I see the full Laravel Mix notification?

Tags: laravel, webpack, laravel-mix

I'm working on a Laravel project with Laravel Mix/Webpack. I'm using `mix watch` on a Mac to compile my asset and whenever it compiles, I get a brief notification about an error. The notification has only enough space for a few lines of text, so I never really know what the message is. There's a `Show` button, but clicking it just closes the notification without bringing up any more information.

[image]

And in the terminal that's running `mix watch` I can see this output:

> 3 WARNINGS in child compilations
> webpack compiled with 3 warnings

Is there a way to see the entire notification or get a more explanatory error message?

Answer (score 5):

Just add the following to your mix configuration (`webpack.mix.js`) and you will see more details in your terminal.

```
mix.webpackConfig({
     stats: {
         hash: true,
         version: true,
         timings: true,
         children: true,
         errors: true,
         errorDetails: true,
         warnings: true,
         chunks: true,
         modules: false,
         reasons: true,
         source: true,
         publicPath: true,
     }
 });
```

See full list of available options here:
[Webpack Documentation](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/)

Comment: Good question, which I also have. The answer does not solve the problem for me, probably because the space in the notification is limited. Is there a way to get the report in the Terminal, instead of as a notification ?